# belongsToMany on not primary field

Tags: php, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.1

For example i have 4 tables: 
**buildings** 
id, title, ... 
**rooms** 
id, building_id, title, ... 
**companies** 
id, title, ... 
**companies_to_buildings** 
company_id, building_id 

and i want to get companies from the room model. 
From building model i can do something like

```
class Building extends Model
{
    public function companies(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_building');
    }
}
```

or

```
class Building extends Model
{
    public function companies(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_building', 'building_id', 'company_id');
    }
}
```

but if i do this in room model, it would not work. it will try to find rows in companies_to_buildings table where companies_to_buildings.building_id=room.id. how can i get companies from the room model?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Example:

```
public function series()
{
return $this->hasManyThrough('Series', 'Product');
}
```

Comment: which models should i use in hasManyThrought?<br />
public function companies(){return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Company', 'App\Building', 'building_id', 'id', 'building_id');}<br />
creates query like<br />
select company.*, building.building_id from company inner join building on building.building_id=company.id where company.deleted=0 and building.building_id in (5)<br />
but i need something like:<br >
select company.*, from company inner join companies_to_buildings on companies_to_buildings.company_id=company.id where company.deleted = 0 and companies_to_buildings.building_id in (5)